# how to split a number into groups of n digits

Tags: javascript

I need to split a number into groups of digits and then place those digits into an array.  I'll then be doing some simple math with those numbers and then inserting them into a textbox.

So far, I have only found how to split a number into individual digits as shown below:

```
var number = 12354987,
output = [],
sNumber = number.toString();

for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i += 1) {
output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Convert it in a string, then split it in substrings and that's all.

Answer (score 13):

You can use regular expression to obtain the result you want.

If you want to group starting by left, the regular expression is quite simple:

```
// assuming you want to group every 3 digits
var number = 12354987,
    output = number.toString().match(/\d{1,3}/g);

// output: ["123", "549", "87"]
```

If, instead, you want to start by right side, e.g. like a currency format, the regular expression needs to be more articulate:

```
var number = 12354987,
    output = number.toString().match(/(\d+?)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)|$)/g);

// output: ["12", "354", "987"]
```

You can change the number of digit you want to group simply replacing `3` inside `\d{3}` with the amount desired. You could also obtain such value from a variable, in that case you have to use the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to build your regexp instance.

**Edit:**
To convert the `output` to numbers again you can use the [array's map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follow:

```
var numbers = output.map(Number);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the "start at right side" version! This saves my day (still, I have to figure out what exactly happens in this regex :-)).

Answer (score 4):

A fairly concise way of doing this would be to use a regular expression. For example, to split the number up into groups of up to 3 digits, you could use the following:

```
number.toString().match(/\d{1,3}/g)
```

This returns the following array:

```
[ "123", "549", "87" ]
```

To split into *N* digits, you can use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor instead:

```
var numDigits = 4;
var re = new RegExp("\\d{1," + numDigits + "}", "g");
var result = number.toString().match(re);
```

Then `result` would be:

```
[ "1235", "4987" ]
```

A simple way to change the values of `result` back into numbers would be to use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), with [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) (which performs a type conversion in a non-constructor context):

```
var numbers = result.map(Number);
```

Then `numbers` would be:

```
[ 1235, 4987 ]
```

Comment: Do you know how achieve this:`'12354987' - ['12','354','987']` ?

Comment: Have used ZER0 answer below.

Comment: Yeah, you could do it using a more complex regex like in that answer. Otherwise, it would be simple enough to achieve using loops and string slices, starting from the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have `output` with individual digits, you can use another array to split it into pieces of `n` size, like so:

```
var n = // your number n;
var final = [];
for(var i = 0; i < output.length / n; i++) {
    final[i] = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        final[i].push(output[(n*i)+j]);
    }
}
```

This outputs an array of arrays of size `n`.

If `n` = 2 it outputs the array (stored in `final`):

```
[
    [1, 2],
    [3, 5],
    [4, 9],
    [8, 7]
]
```

See working example [on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0fLtmu/1/).

Answer (score 0):

While there may be a simpler way to do this using Regexp, you could try this:

```
var splitNumber = function (number, digits) {
    var numString = number.toString();
    var numArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < numString.length; i+=digits) {
        numArray.push(numString.substring(i, i+digits));
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
        numArray[i] = Number(numArray[i]);
    }
    return numArray;
}
```